# The requested URL returned error: 403 Forbidden while accessing github.com

Tags: git, github

So, I have a repo setup, on another machine. I've committed and pushed files and they view fine on github.com. Now, I have ran `git init` on another machine and I'm trying to pull.

```
# git remote set-url origin git@github.com:me/someproj.git
fatal: No such remote 'origin'

# git remote add origin https://github.com/me/someproj.git

# git pull
error: The requested URL returned error: 403 Forbidden while accessing https://github.com/me/someproj.git/info/refs

fatal: HTTP request failed

# git remote -v
origin  https://github.com/me/someproj.git (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/me/someproj.git (push)

# git pull origin
error: The requested URL returned error: 403 Forbidden while accessing https://github.com/me/someproj.git/info/refs

fatal: HTTP request failed
```

Comment: Please provide more info - which git version are you using on that machine ? Did you set you username and password ? Are you behind a firewall or using a proxy ?

Comment: git version 1.7.1 and no i'm not behind a proxy, that i know of. i'm not sure if I've set a user/pass.

Comment: So that's probably your problem, set it up with ```git config --global user.name your_username``` and do the same for your password.

Comment: @ShmulikKlein user.name has nothing to do with authentication though.

Answer (score 12):

You need to check what credential (username/password) you are using on the machine where a push to GitHub succeed, and re-use those credential in your new local repo.

Check especially the type of url used: ssh (`git@github.com:me/someproj.git`) or https (`https://github.com/me/someproj.git`).
Check also if you were [using 2FA (Two-Factor Authentication)](https://help.github.com/articles/about-two-factor-authentication/) or not for that GitHub account and repos.

You can embed the [right username in your url](http://403%20Forbidden%20while%20accessing)::

```
cd /path/to/new/local/repo
git remote add origin https://me@github.com/me/someproj.git
```

Answer (score 2):

When trying to access https://github.com/me/someproj.git/info/refs from the browser you'll notice the following message which associated with a 403 status code:

> Please upgrade your git client. GitHub.com no longer supports git over
>   dumb-http:
>   https://github.com/blog/809-git-dumb-http-transport-to-be-turned-off-in-90-days

If you are using git prior to 1.6.6, try to update it or better use a SSH protocol.

Also check your setup with `git config --global user.name` and `git config --global user.password`.

Answer (score 2):

You can try the `git remote -v` command to check the remote repo URL is ok.
If it is not, you should  try

```
git remote set-url origin repo-url
```

To fix any typos

Answer (score 2):

If you use two account in same computer it will throw this error.

[image]

In windows 10
Control Panel -> User Accounts -> Manage your credentials.
Remove the github account.

Answer (score 1):

> For those whose problem is not solved with deleting the credential or url change.

I strongly recommend to check that you have the permission to push to the repo. To make sure, ask the repo's admin to give you the **WRITE** permission in the '**Manage Access**' section of the repo's settings.
Hope this works for you.

[image: the manage access section in github]
[image: add contributor]