# git repository gives 403 error while connecting from jenkins in linux

Tags: git, github, jenkins, build, centos

Hi I just want to configure my project from github to jenkins to generate build.
I'm getting following error

```
Failed to connect to repository : Command "/usr/bin/git ls-remote -h 
https://github.com/xxxxx/yyyyy.git HEAD" 
returned status code 128:
stdout: 
stderr: error: The requested URL returned error: 403 Forbidden while 
accessing https://github.com/xxxxx/yyyyy.git/info/refs

fatal: HTTP request failed
```

[image]

I have added git path at Global Tool Configuration also.  I've setup jenkins in linux centos server.

I have found few similar questions in stackoverflow but that doesn't give a solution

Can anyone please tell me what may be wrong in that ?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The requested URL returned error: 403 Forbidden while accessing github.com](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37982046/the-requested-url-returned-error-403-forbidden-while-accessing-github-com)

Comment: I have looked at answers of above question and tried in that way but couldn't resolved this.  and here I'm using jenkins which installed in linux centos

Comment: Since you using an https URL, is your credential matching your GitHub login/password (hint: your locgin is not an email address). And do you have 2FA (two-factor authentication) activated for your GitHub account?

Comment: Yes credentials are matching with GitHub account and I don't have 2FA activated.

Comment: It is working fine when I have added username & password in url like https://username:password@github.com/xxxxxx/yyyyy.git. along with credentials option shown in image.  But I don't want to show password in the URL. Is there any other way to solve this ?

Comment: Why your credential entry name includes an email address?

Comment: Can you check that process in another machine like windows for your conformation whether fault with URL or the Permissions provided in the Linux machine for git access and jenkins.

Comment: @VonC : It is working fine with above scenario ( my previous comment ) with username which not include email address.

Comment: @ChandraSekhar : Yes it is working fine in windows ( without giving username & password in URL ).

Comment: Are you using Private repository in git?
Check with the permissions of git installation in your machine.

Comment: Are you working with the jenkins in HTTP or HTTPS??

Answer (score 6):

A bit late, but this solutions works for me. Just change the URL from

```
 https://github.com/xxxxx/yyyyy.git
```

to

```
 https://youruser@github.com/xxxxx/yyyyy.git
```

Comment: @Sree --> Please mark this as the accepted answer. This worked beautifully for us after struggling to figure out the issue for several days now.

Answer (score 2):

I also faced similar issue when configuring GIT in jenkins. After some investigation I found out that jenkins using default git installation which is 1.7.1 version. Then I installed the latest version and configured jenkins to use the latest version. Click on **Maange Jenkins** -> **Global Tool Configuration** -> **Git** to find the configuration section.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try creating an SSH Key. This will allow passwordless communication between your jenkins server and Github.

Run the following commands from your jenkins server(as root):

```
sudo su -s /bin/bash jenkins
cd ~
ssh-keygen -t rsa  (Hit enter for all prompts)
cat .ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

Then, login to the github UI, go to SSH Keys, then paste the output of the last command into a new key.

You should be good to go at this point.