# Unable to access github repo from Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins

I did setup

1) Github Oauth in Configure Global Security where I had to specify clientID, secret and so on..

2) I also added public key of jenkins machine to my github account

3) I go to blueocean and try to create pipeline so it asks me for personal access token so I do that and successfully create a pipeline.

**Now I run a simple Job but it fails because it is unable to connect to the repo. not sure why?**

```
> git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree # timeout=10
Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
 > git config remote.origin.url https://github.com/helloinc/test-repo.git # timeout=10
Fetching without tags
Fetching upstream changes from https://github.com/helloinc/test-repo.git
 > git --version # timeout=10
using GIT_ASKPASS to set credentials GitHub Access Token
 > git fetch --no-tags --progress https://github.com/helloinc/test-repo.git +refs/heads/jenkins-test:refs/remotes/origin/jenkins-test
ERROR: Error fetching remote repo 'origin'
hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Failed to fetch from https://github.com/helloinc/test-repo.git
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.fetchFrom(GitSCM.java:817)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.retrieveChanges(GitSCM.java:1084)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.checkout(GitSCM.java:1115)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.scm.SCMStep.checkout(SCMStep.java:113)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.scm.SCMStep$StepExecutionImpl.run(SCMStep.java:85)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.scm.SCMStep$StepExecutionImpl.run(SCMStep.java:75)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.AbstractSynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution$1$1.call(AbstractSynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.java:47)
    at hudson.security.ACL.impersonate(ACL.java:260)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.AbstractSynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution$1.run(AbstractSynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.java:44)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command "git fetch --no-tags --progress https://github.com/helloinc/test-repo.git +refs/heads/jenkins-test:refs/remotes/origin/jenkins-test" returned status code 128:
stdout: 
stderr: error: The requested URL returned error: 403 Forbidden while accessing https://github.com/helloinc/test-repo.git/info/refs

fatal: HTTP request failed
```

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43001916/7796750) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37982046/7796750) are closely related, check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38032282/7796750).

Comment: try to check first it is authenticated with your GitHUB account by `ssh -T git@github.com`

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with jenkins, but perhaps you should not use the HTTP protocol.

Try to change the remote url of the clone:

```
git remote set-url origin git@github.com:helloinc/test-repo.git
```

Comment: I am not sure where? The UI is so confusing and all over the place

Comment: Do you input the full URL manually? If yes, just redo from this step with a new one.

Comment: No. It automatically configures it

Comment: Looks like you can use the UI to pop a console and `cd` to the correct directory in order to tweak the URL.