# Push failed: Failed with error: Could not read from remote repository

Tags: git, android-studio, github

I'm getting following dialog in Android Studio on trying to push code to newly created public repo on github.com (Dialog appeared 3 times!)

> > Confirm ssh key
> >     connecting to host github.com:22 that has key fdsfdfd:dfdf . Do you want to add to know hosts?
> >     
> >  Yes or No

After selecting `yes`, push is getting failed.

> Push failed: Failed with error: Could not read from remote repository.

Note:
I've freshly installed git(after uninstalling previous git & restarted PC) & there is no .gitconfig file on root.

How to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you have the right permissions on the remote repository. If yes, try re-adding remote repository: VCS -> Git -> Remotes.

Comment: It is now saying " The requested URL returned error: 403". Its not giving login dialog either.

Comment: @AskQ Seems you are having the same problem as stated in the following issues. Please take a look at the voted answer

https://stackoverflow.com/a/38032282/1084126